# C++ class destructor not working properly

Tags: c++, destructor

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
class Animal
{
protected:
int age;
char* name;
public:
Animal()
{
    name=new char[1];
    age = 0;
    strcpy(name," ");
}
Animal(int _age, char* _name)
{
    age=_age;
    name = new char[strlen(_name)+1];
    strcpy(name, _name);
}

~Animal()
{
    delete[] name;
}

friend istream& operator >>(istream& in, Animal& a);
friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out,  const Animal& a);

};
 istream& operator >>(istream& in, Animal& a)
{
    in>>a.name>>a.age;
    return in;
}
 ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Animal& a)
{
    out<<a.name<<a.age;
    return out;
}


int main()
{
Animal a;
cin>>a;
cout<<a;
return 0;
}
```

This piece of code gives me the opportunity to enter `a`, then prints it and then the screen freezes and stops working. If I delete the destructor, it works properly. Why is this happening? And is it because of the destructor really?

Comment: Why are you using `cstring` instead of `std::string`?

Comment: You have undefined behaviour. You are accessing `name` out of bounds here: `strcpy(name," ");`. Fix that first. Then, fix the next undefined behaviour.

Comment: Always allocate at least 1 extra char for the `'\0'` terminating char

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There are several bugs in your code.
The first one is in the constructor

```
Animal()
{
    name=new char[1];
    age = 0;
    strcpy(name," ");
}
```

String literal `" "` consists from two characters: the space character and the terminating zero '\0;. So you need to allocate dynamically 2 bytes

```
    name=new char[2];
```

that to use after that function strcpy.

Or instead of string literal `" "` you should use "an empty" string literal `""` that contains only the terminating zero '\0'.

The other bug in function

```
 istream& operator >>(istream& in, Animal& a)
{
    in>>a.name>>a.age;
    return in;
}
```

As you initially allocated only 1 byte pointed to by name then you may not use operator

```
    in>>a.name;
```

because you will overwrite memory that does not belong to the allocated extent.

For example you could define the operator the following way

```
std::istream& operator >>( std::istream& in, Animal &a )
{
    char itsName[25]; 

    in >> itsName >> a.age;

    char *tmp = new char[std::strlen( itsName ) + 1];

    std::strcpy( tmp, itsName );

    delete [] name;

    name = tmp;

    return in;
}
```

In this case you could enter a name that does not exceed 24 characters.

Take into account that you need also to define a copy constructor and the copy assignment operator if you are going to assign one object to another.

Comment: 3 downvotes and no good reason for them. Sometimes, I wonder why we even bother to answer such questions...

Answer (score 4):

You allocate a C-string having the size 1 and copy the C-string " " having the size 2 to it. Also you read an unknown amount of characters to the name in 'istream& operator >>(istream& in, Animal& a)`. Both will corrupt the memory the name is pointing to and both can be easily fix by using std::string:

```
class Animal
{
    protected:
    int age;
    std::string name;

    public:
    Animal()
    : age(0)
    {}

    Animal(int age_, std::string name_)
    : age(age_), name(name_)
    {}
};
```

This avoids writing a destructor and copy-constructor and assignment operator, which are missing in your code (See: [Rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)).

Answer (score 3):

If you really don't want to use `std::string`, your best bet is something in the line of ([live at coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99eec0451277b2de)):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

class Animal {
private:
  // copy a string
  inline static char* dstr(const char* string) {
    if( !string ) return NULL;
    size_t l = strlen(string);
    if( !l ) return NULL;
    return strcpy(new char[++l], string);
  }
protected:
  int age;
  char* name;
public:
  // initialize an "empty" Animal
  Animal() : age(0), name(NULL) {}

  // initialize an animal by age and name
  Animal(int _age, const char* _name): age(_age), name(dstr(_name)) {}

  // initialize an animal from another animal:
  // copy the name string
  Animal(const Animal& _a): age(_a.age), name(dstr(_a.name)) {}

  // assign an animal from another animal:
  // first delete the string you have, then copy the string
  Animal& operator=(const Animal& _a) {
    // for exception-safety, save the old "name" pointer,
    // then try to allocate a new one; if it throws, nothing happens
    // to *this...
    char* oldname = name;
    name = dstr(_a.name);
    age = _a.age;
    delete[] oldname;
    return *this;
  }

  // if C++11
  // we have something called "move" constructor and assignment
  // these are used, for instance, in "operator>>" below
  // and they assume that _a will soon be deleted
  Animal(Animal&& _a): Animal() {
    swap(age, _a.age);
    swap(name, _a.name);
  }
  Animal& operator=(Animal&& _a) {
    swap(age, _a.age);
    swap(name, _a.name);
    return *this;
  }
  
  ~Animal() { delete[] name; }

  friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out,  const Animal& a);

};

istream& operator >>(istream& in, Animal& a) {
  const size_t MAX_ANIMAL_NAME = 2048;
  int age;
  char n[MAX_ANIMAL_NAME+1];
  if( in.getline(n, MAX_ANIMAL_NAME) >> age )
    a = Animal(age, n);
  return in;
}

ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Animal& a) {
  return out<<a.name<<endl<<a.age<<endl;
}


int main() {
  Animal a { 23, "bobo" };
  cout<<a;
  cin>>a;
  cout<<a;
}
```

This does not leak memory, does not have undefined behaviours, and does not have buffer overruns.

You can also segregate the "need to manage memory" to a separate class:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

class AnimalName {
  private:
    char *n;
    inline static char* dstr(const char* string) {
      if( !string ) return NULL;
      size_t l = strlen(string);
      if( !l ) return NULL;
      return strcpy(new char[++l], string);
    }
  public:
    AnimalName() : AnimalName(NULL) {}
    AnimalName(const char *_n) : n(dstr(_n)) {}
    AnimalName(const AnimalName& _n) : n(dstr(_n.n)) {}
    // see exception-safety issue above
    AnimalName& operator=(const AnimalName& _n) { char *on = n; n = dstr(_n.n); delete[] on; return *this; }
    AnimalName(AnimalName&& _n) : AnimalName() { swap(n, _n.n); }
    AnimalName& operator=(AnimalName&& _n) { swap(n, _n.n); return *this; }
    ~AnimalName() { delete[] n; }

    operator const char*() const { return n; }
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& i, AnimalName& n) {
      const size_t MAX_ANIMAL_NAME = 2048;
      char name[MAX_ANIMAL_NAME+1];
      if( i.getline(name, MAX_ANIMAL_NAME) )
        n = name;
      return i;
    }
};

class Animal {
protected:
  int age;
  AnimalName name;
public:
  // initialize an "empty" Animal
  Animal() : age(0) {}

  // initialize an animal by age and name
  Animal(int _age, const char* _name): age(_age), name(_name) {}

  friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out,  const Animal& a) {
    return out<<a.name<<endl<<a.age<<endl;
  }
};

istream& operator >>(istream& in, Animal& a) {
  AnimalName n;
  int age;
  if( in >> n >> age )
    a = Animal(age, n);
  return in;
}


int main() {
  Animal a { 23, "bobo" };
  cout<<a;
  cin>>a;
  cout<<a;
  return 0;
}
```

This way you get to follow the "[rule of zero](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/)" (basically, classes that do not have the *sole* responsibility of managing memory/resources should *not* manage memory and therefore should **not** implement copy/move-constructors, assignments, or destructors.)

And that takes us to the **real** reason why you should use `std::string`: it not only does the memory management for you, but it also takes good care of your IO needs, eliminating the need for a "maximum animal name" in your example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class Animal {
protected:
  string name; // name first, for exception-safety on auto-gen assignment?
  int age;
public:
  // initialize an "empty" Animal
  Animal() : age(0) {}

  // initialize an animal by age and name
  Animal(int _age, const string& _name): age(_age), name(_name) {}

  friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out,  const Animal& a) {
    return out<<a.name<<endl<<a.age<<endl;
  }
};

istream& operator >>(istream& in, Animal& a) {
  string n;
  int age;
  if( getline(in, n) >> age )
    a = Animal(age, n);
  return in;
}


int main() {
  Animal a { 23, "bobo" };
  cout<<a;
  cin>>a;
  cout<<a;
}
```

Comment: @Massa - One issue though is that your assignment operator in the first `Animal` class is not exception safe.  You're deallocating `name` before allocating for a new name.  If `new` throws an exception, your Animal object is corrupted.  That is a further reason why std::string should be used.

Comment: To continue - It is also the reason why (IMO) asking students to "not use std::string" is a dangerous game to play with the students learning C++.  The assignment the student finally hands in as the "completed assignment" is incorrect in some way that only an intermediate or expert C++ programmer would spot.  It does the student no good if they're completing assignments wrought with bugs that they are never told about (except on SO and other sites), with the student having a false sense of accomplishment.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I corrected the error, but your remark about `std::string` are absolutely correct! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A simple fix is to use **`std::string`** for your strings.

It almost doesn't matter what the specific errors you get are. But just to cover that, already in the constructor of `Animal`,

```
Animal()
{
    name=new char[1];
    age = 0;
    strcpy(name," ");
}
```

you have Undefined Behavior by allocating just a single element array and then using `strcpy` top copy two `char` values there. Overwriting some memory after the array.

Then in `operator>>` the UB trend continues.

And so forth.

Use `std::string`.

Comment: Note, that the first UB will not cause a crash on any common platform, because the actual allocated memory is always multiple of 4 or more bytes.

Comment: @JanHudec: that depends on the allocator, not on the platform. it might be the small item allocator from the Loki library. for example.

Comment: Of course (except on many platforms it is practically impossible to override their default allocator).

Answer (score 1):

Your memory management is wrong, which is corrupting the memory. You are allocating space for *one character* for `name`. But

```
strcpy(name," ");
```

will pass beyond the memory you allocated, since `cstring` is `null` terminated, it will put actually two character, effectively corrupting your memory ( you are accessing memory that is not allocated by your program). It itself has **undefined behavior**.

Further you are deleting an apparently unknown  amount of memory in the destructor, which has also **undefined behavior**.

Comment: In other words, he should allocate an array of 2 chars in this case

Comment: @user3322273: I would probably incline more to copying empty string (`""`) in there.

Comment: So how should look our default constructor ? Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "deleting an apparently unknown amount of memory"? Perhaps I am dumb today, but as far as I know `delete[]` does not need to know the amount of memory, it only needs to know the exact type, which it does.

Comment: Of course the other thing is that memory is always allocated at least in multiples of 4, so while allocating 1 byte and writing 2 bytes is undefined behaviour, in practice I don't think it's likely to cause the problem.

Comment: @user253956, change the allocation size to 2 chars, or change the string you assign to `""`, instead of `" "` (An empty string instead of string that contains a single space)

Comment: @user253956: Actually, the _other_ error, pointed out by Vlad, is the thing that makes it all crash and burn.

Comment: @JanHudec, compiler must maintain the amount of memory allocated in order to delete safely, what I meant is, because of the overrun in allocated memory which is UB, the heap data structure may get corrupted, which may effect the functionality of `delete` operator. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @RakibulHasan: That's what happens, but the error is writing past the end of the allocated area, not "deleting unknown amount of memory". The amount of memory to be deleted is known, but undefined behaviour happened when overruning it that may have any effect and a likely effect is that it makes the `delete` crash and burn.

Comment: If someone could please sum it all up and tell me exacly how the code looks like, I would be very grateful. I am getting really confused.AND PLEASE DON'T USE std::string.

Comment: @user253956 the code in the answer given by Dieter Lücking is the better. But if you really don't want to use `std::string`, I'll post another answer.

Comment: @user253956 - If you *should* use pointers, use advises from Vlad from Moscow's answer. Note that this is better to do only when you know exactly what and why you are doing. Otherwise, take "C++-style" advice to use std::string.

Comment: @user253956 :: see new answer.